# Subtraction query in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have following data

```
select * from t_operation

date_operation ntype_operation  summa    summa_som course_valname datecourse
-------------- ---------------  -----    --------- -------------- ----------
3/15/20017        BUY            100       7392       EUR          3/15/20017  
3/15/20017        SELL           100       7594       EUR          3/15/20017
```

I need to write a query which will tacke summa_som = 7594 - 7392 = 202 as INCOME
summa_som i get through update using function

```
update t_operation
set summa_som = get_rate(date_operation,course_valname,upper(substr(ntype_operation,1,1))) * trunc(summa)
where summa is null
```

Function is

```
create or replace function get_rate(p_date date, p_ccy varchar2, p_bs varchar2)
return number
is
v_ret_val number;
begin

SELECT --R.* ,
       CASE p_bs
       when 'B' then buy else sell end retval into v_ret_val
FROM T_COURSE_RATES R
JOIN (
select COURSE_VALNAME,MAX(DATECOURSE) AS MAXD from T_COURSE_RATES t
WHERE DATECOURSE <= TRUNC(p_date)
GROUP BY COURSE_VALNAME) T2
ON R.COURSE_VALNAME = T2.COURSE_VALNAME AND R.DATECOURSE = T2.MAXD
   and r.course_valname = p_ccy;

return  v_ret_val;

  end;
```

Comment: How to you know how to pair bye/sell?

Comment: As @jarlh says, you need another field to define how to group the data

Comment: What do you mean ? i added some code how i calculated ammount_conv field may be there will be idea

Comment: What everyone means is this:  Suppose you have six rows with the same amount, `100`, three are BUY and three are SELL, all six are in USD "course", and all with different amount of conversion. Which BUY is paired with which SELL? Or do you, in fact, need an AGGREGATE profit, combining ALL the transactions? (And if so, how do you group - by currency? Or how else?) Normally, in real life, each "sell" is tied to one or more "buys" so you can compute individual profit or loss on each trade or portion of a trade.

Comment: i added to question table t_currency

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just want conditional aggregation:

```
select amount_conv,
       sum(case when type_operation = 'SELL' then amount
                when type_operation = 'BUY' then - amount
                else 0
           end) as income,
       course
from t
group by amount_conv, course;
```

I'm not sure why you would want `SELL` in the second column.  On the other hand `course` seems like a useful column to put in the result set.

Comment: its works but not what i want. i want ammount of sell_operation subtract with buy_operation * ammount and i will get profit because sell value greater than buy value

Comment: else trunc(summa * 69.9 / 69.1 ) something like this

Comment: 69.9 value he will tacke from sell field , 69.1 will tacke from buy field so i get income by selling higher than actually it is

Comment: @СмокБелью . . . I would suggest that you ask *another* question and try to better explain what your problem is, perhaps with more appropriate data.

Comment: i edited question if wont be answer ill create another question

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a column that defines how the values are paired:

```
select SomeOtherField, -- This is the column that defines which values become pairs
       sum(case
             when type_operation = 'SELL' then ammount_conv 
             else ammount_conv * -1 
           end) as Profit
from MyTable
group by SomeOtherField
```

Comment: Why there sum before (case ?

Comment: @СмокБелью Because you will sum the outcome of the case